# Create enumerated files in a 'for' using shell script (file1, file2, file3...)

Tags: linux, shell, concatenation

Is there a way to create enumerated files using `for` in shell script?
For instance, when

- 'i' is 2 => file2 is created
- 'i' is 3 => file 3 is created

How do I concatenate the 'i' value to file name?

Thanks!

Comment: You are interested in `for i in 1 2 3; do touch file_${i}; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 20`;
do
   touch file${i}
done
```

creating sequence files using a range, in this case 1 to 20.